# A variable as a list

Tags: ksh

I am on Solaris 2.10 with ksh "Version M-11/16/88i".

I have some problems with the list in a "for".

First example works as I want:

```
#!/bin/ksh
for i in ONE "one is 1" TWO "two is 2" THREE three
do
echo $i
done
```

The output of this is:

```
> ./mytest.ksh 
ONE
one is 1
TWO
two is 2
THREE
three
>
```

But, if I change the code to something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh
MYVAR="ONE \"one is 1\" TWO \"two is 2\" THREE three"
echo "MYVAR=$MYVAR"
for i in $MYVAR
do
echo $i
done
```

Then the output is:

```
> ./mytest.ksh 
MYVAR=ONE "one is 1" TWO "two is 2" THREE three
ONE
"one
is
1"
TWO
"two
is
2"
THREE
three
>
```

How could I keep the values in the variable MYVAR so as the loop FOR takes it correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: what you need? Just one string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYVAR="ONE \"one is 1\", TWO \"two is 2\", THREE three"
export IFS=",";
echo "MYVAR=$MYVAR"
for i in $MYVAR
do
echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting while echoeing like:

```
MYVAR="ONE \"one is 1\" TWO \"two is 2\" THREE three"
echo "MYVAR=$MYVAR"
for i in "$MYVAR"
         ^      ^
do
    echo $i
done    
Output:
MYVAR=ONE "one is 1" TWO "two is 2" THREE three                                                                        
ONE "one is 1" TWO "two is 2" THREE three
```